# What Mathematica versions do people use?

Tags: discussion

Those who develop packages need to decide what Mathematica versions to support.  It would be useful to know what is the usage share of different versions.

I am not aware of any information being published on this, but we can make our own survey!

Here it is:

- http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1361199

Please fill it out!

---

<sup>Note: Results from the previous survey round, advertised only on Wolfram Community, is already published. I posted here in an effort to get more responses.</sup>

Comment: Saw this over on WC and answered. :)

Comment: So many already on 11.3. I'm still developing with compatibility for 10.0 in mind.

Comment: Is there anywhere where the new results might be posted? (assuming the result count is sufficient)

Comment: @b3m2a1 Wanted to do the community ad first, but that had to be put off ... I'll post it soon.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/xEIoE.png

Comment: Will there be an update for results - after all there is summer vacation time?

Comment: @gwr I wanted to do an update but unfortunately my computer use ability is still quite impaired due to a problem with my wrist. Because of this I'm quite behind with important work and just couldn't find the time to do less urgent projects.

Comment: Any news on this topic?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for the reminder. My wrist is well now and I will update it over the weekend.